# Singularity ERROR : Failed to mount image in (read only): Invalid argument

Tags: docker, singularity-container

I try to build a singularity image from a docker image located on dockerhub.

```
singularity build pcgr.simg docker://sigven/pcgr:0.5.3
```

Then when I try yo execute it :

```
singularity exec pcgr.simg ls
```

It gives me this error :

```
ERROR  : Failed to mount image in (read only): Invalid argument
ABORT  : Retval = 255
```

singularity version : 2.3.1-dist

Any idea how to solve this ?

Thank you

P.S. : Here's the lines printed during the build

```
/usr/local/libexec/singularity/cli/build.exec: ligne 62: atexit : commande introuvable
Docker image path: index.docker.io/sigven/pcgr:0.5.3
Cache folder set to /home/user/.singularity/docker
Importing: base Singularity environment
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:ae79f251470513c2a0ec750117a81f2d58a50727901ca416efecf297b8a03913.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:5ad56d5fc14905886c560200ab69f905b5c5287eaf12f8f761a7ab54f7a61c1b.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:170e558760e8b2e484a022b7d7272cf284fc4e1936ba7a0a671fc586440ad272.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:395460e233f5bdcd910d618a3b615e0d881e09ad27d58f3065eef53ecae6a808.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:6f01dc62e444044e3ce494269837ef0aedb80fef69c679416137f17812d2eb9c.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:a409104b96312ca9097e28dde2973b6be718b1fe6eb88c7256abc676adeef5fc.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:0c502e44f6cf92ed12bccaa5250fe50b6002f8c2802ccaeb10897095965ebc9a.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:2d356fa216d078e32e78c4279b81407f40c39160c8b6479ca248659f39f4f38e.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:4a160e3926c74bcfadac2c55d8da45847b3f45d110c6f56efc3355322bbbe270.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:dda5a77ec5fea4fed769435dce43d7cbecb820229bcb977fe43f89d539a17efe.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:edb264ed4f1cb0ff53211e09c68f904bedfa0f2ffa9556f0a41db9ef29ebe12f.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:ceeedca91fedbc58ab16627f6af0c3b8d150d8242a5a6956c6bc8969e8384806.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:0be25d4ff93e0b0b51d64ad5e9dec58f4dc4993cd474a1a11960f2ca8c08736d.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/docker/sha256:cba09c9b27f7c7e5bccd8e10202466714b77eacb7b503b92e5d9ee1c4ee0a903.tar.gz
Importing: /home/user/.singularity/metadata/sha256:99759e9893f4fa0e30b37531d92efbcbcd79e85733c0c8cee3cc6ac1495164ed.tar.gz
/usr/local/libexec/singularity/cli/build.exec: ligne 325: nonroot_build_warning : commande introuvable
Building Singularity image...

Singularity container built: pcgr.simg
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to wrap my head around the way singularity works (coming with Docker experience, singularity is a little confusing) but I found that similar errors are bypassed by running your command with `sudo`.

Still reading what the implications of that, though, is...

Answer (score 0):

by default singuarity mounts / dev / tmp and $ HOME, but you are building an immutable image (**simg**) without elevated privileges, this means that you do not have root rights when mounting OS directories, you have several options, modify the configuration in `/etc/singularity/singularity.conf` so that you do not mount those directories or create the image with sudo.

```
sudo singularity build pcgr.simg docker: // sigven / pcgr: 0.5.3
```